# How easily can the key of a .NET assembly be cracked?

Tags: .net

If I sign a .NET assembly and do not give out my private key, how much effort would it take for somebody to crack the private key?

Comment: With which particular method of signing? Strong Naming, or code signing? And of what size key?

Comment: @SteveS: Strong naming.

Answer (score 2):

It would take the same amount of effort as trying to falsify any other signing operation or rather trying to get the private key from any other signature.  Generally speaking though, the most common attack is to try to make a different file that collides with the hash in the signature rather than trying to get the private key.